# Theorem about dense and closed sets

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

> Let X a topological space. A subset $A \subset X$ is said to be dense in $X$, if $\overline{A}=X$. $A$ is said to be nowhere dense in $X$, if $(\overline{A})^{°}=\emptyset$. If $A\subset X$ is closed, then $A$ is nowhere dense in $X$, if $X\setminus A$ is dense in $X$. Is this theorem valid for any set?

I'm absolutely confused and disorientated to begin the argumentation. Do you have any hints, to start or think at?

Thank you!

Comment: Hint: Let $X=\mathbb{R},\;A=\mathbb{Q}$. Would you say $X\setminus A$ is dense in $X$?

Comment: Yes it is, because $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q} \exists r>0$ so that $d(x,y)<r$.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that $A$ is closed. Ignore my hint -- sorry.

Comment: Ah okay! No problem, thanks for effort :-)

Comment: @quasi I think your hint was right. Despite the proofs below, my professor said that we have to looking for a counterexample. And $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}=\mathbb{R}\cup\mathbb{Q}'$, whereby $\mathbb{Q}'$ is the set with all limit points. And this is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, but $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, so the proposition is wrong.

Comment: No, my hint wasn't right. And your professor perhaps made the same mistake. The hypothesis requires the set $A$ to be closed. The posted answers are correct.

Comment: Ah, that seems possible, right. So, thank you for correcting this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $X \setminus A$ is dense in $X$,
$\overline{X \setminus A} = X$

$\Rightarrow X \setminus A^{\circ} = X$

$\Rightarrow A^{\circ} = \emptyset$

$\Rightarrow \overline{A}^{\circ} = \emptyset \quad$ since $A$ is closed, which implies that $A$ is nowhere dense in X.

Edit: We prove that $\overline{X \setminus A} = X \setminus A^{\circ}$ by showing that they are contained in each other:
Let $A'$ represent the set of limit points of $A$.
Consider $x \in \overline{X \setminus A} = X \setminus A \cup \left(X \setminus A \right)'$

If $x \in X \setminus A \subseteq X \setminus A^{\circ}$ (since $A^{\circ} \subseteq A$ always)

$\Rightarrow \overline{X \setminus A} \subseteq X \setminus A^{\circ}$

On the other hand, if $x \in \left(X \setminus A \right)'$, then $\forall \, \epsilon > 0$ we have:

$N_{\epsilon}(x) \cap \left(\left(X \setminus A \right)\setminus \{x\}\right) \neq \emptyset$

$\Rightarrow N_{\epsilon}(x)\not\subseteq \left( X \setminus \left(X \setminus A\right) \setminus \{x\} \right) = A \cup \{x\}$

$\Rightarrow N_{\epsilon}(x) \not\subseteq A$

So $x$ is not an interior point of $A$.

$\Rightarrow x \in X \setminus A^{\circ}$

$\Rightarrow \overline{X \setminus A} \subseteq X \setminus A^{\circ} $

Conversely, let $x \in  X \setminus A^{\circ}$

$\Rightarrow \forall \, \epsilon > 0 \, \, N_{\epsilon}(x) \not \subseteq A$

$\Rightarrow N_{\epsilon}(x) \cap X \setminus A \neq \emptyset $

$\Rightarrow x$ is a limit point of $A$ or a point of $A$ or both,

$\Rightarrow x \in  X \setminus A \cup \left(X \setminus A \right)' = \overline{X \setminus A}$

$\Rightarrow  X \setminus A^{\circ}\subseteq \overline{X \setminus A}$

Thus $X \setminus A^{\circ}= \overline{X \setminus A}$

Comment: Can you explain the first step from $\overline{X\setminus A}$ to $X\setminus A^o$ more detailed and the conclusion from $\overline{A}^o$ to nowhere dense?

Comment: Edited the answer to explain the equality of those two sets. The conclusion follows from the definition you gave in your question for a nowhere dense set.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, a theorem valid in any space $X$ for any subset $A$ is:

$$X \setminus A^\circ = \overline{X \setminus A}$$ from which your fact follows immediately.

($x$ is not in the interior of $A$ iff there is no open set containing $x$ that stays inside $A$ iff every open set that contains $x$ intersects $X \setminus A$ iff $x$ is in the closure of $X\setminus A$.)